# Unmeasurable observables in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, observables, quantum-measurements

Let's consider a single particle in 1D harmonic oscillator for definiteness. In standard QM, we say that any Hermitian operator on the Hilbert space is an "observable". It seems that (in theory) we can measure the probability distribution induced by $H, P, X$ with arbitrary precision, i.e. for an large collection of identically prepared states, we could figure out the norm of the overlaps with the energy, position, and momentum eigenstates.

On the other hand, even in theory, it's not clear to me that most of the observables are experimentally measurable. Taking for example arbitrary self adjoint product of $X,P$, such as $X^n P^m X^n$, $XPXPXPX$, etc. Is there any reason to think we could even measure the expectations of these operators? Are there any references discussing the possibility of measuring these observables?

Edit: A clarification following some points made in the comments. The question is whether or not we should expect to be able to construct experimental apparatuses that measure these observables. Of course, if we were able to construct a physical system which had a given observable as a Hamiltonian, we could measure it by measuring energy. But is there any evidence that observables of the above form are physically measurable by constructing these physical systems? Or any discussions in the literature about this problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible to measure $\langle X^n P^m X^n\rangle$? I'm not sure there are references describing that operator specifically because it's kind of a random combination and doesn't have any particular meaning in general. But I don't see why you wouldn't be able to measure it if you really wanted to. Also note the angular momentum operators have a similar structure, eg $L_z = x P_y - y P_x$.

Comment: @Andrew You shouldn't be able to measure it precisely because it doesn't have any physical meaning, is the intuition. The angular momentum operators are really pretty different, since $X$ and $P_Y$ commute, for one thing, so we can compute $XP_Y$ expectation from just knowing the joint probability distribution w/r/t $X$ and $P_Y$, which are simultaneously measurable. Similarly for $YP_X$. For another, since it is a real physical quantity, we can directly come up with experiments to measure it.

Comment: Are you asking a question of principle or practice? In principle you can imagine there's some probe that couples to $X^n P^m X^n$, and then measuring that probe will put the state into eigenstates of $X^n P^m X^n$. In practice I don't know if anyone has actually come up with such a probe, since why bother. But that's just a practical issue. We *could* in theory observe this quantity, and quantum mechanics tells us what we would get if we did. But, we *don't* actually measure this quantity, because it's useless.

Comment: @Andrew It's not just a practical issue if there is no such probe. Of course if generically we can construct probes of this form and no one has gotten around to the specific case of $X^5 P^10 X^5$ that'd be one thing. But in actuality, it seems to be the case that we cannot construct *any* probes to measure any quantum observable that is not a "real physical quantity" such as position, momentum, angular momentum, energy, etc. *or directly deducible from these quantities.*

Comment: So the question stands as to whether there is any way to measure these not apparently measurable quantities. It really doesn't seem sufficient to me to say that we could imagine some way to measure them. It's not at all clear to me we could.

Comment: It's easy to construct a probe like that in principle. Just add the following interaction to the Hamiltonian $H_{int}=X^n P^m X^n \phi$ where $\phi$ is an operator telling you the output of the probe. The output of the probe will be determined by the operator $X^n P^m X^n$. The fact that we haven't built a device to measure $\phi$ in a lab is not relevant to the point of principle that quantum mechanics tells us what we would see if we did build it.

Comment: @Andrew How do we experimentally construct Hamiltonians with arbitrary Hermitian interactions though? I'm not aware of a way to do this, but I'm also not too familiar with the practicalities of quantum experimentation.

Comment: There's not a general procedure. You'd have to find some set of interactions where the probe coupled to $X^n P^m X^n$. But I think there's two questions here. The first is: what is the interpretation of saying $X^n P^m X^n$ is an observable. We mean *if you built a probe that measured that quantity*, QM tells you what you would measure for that observable in any state. That's all I'm saying. The other question is, how do you actually build an experimental probe of that quantity? Probably, it's annoying and hard to do that for arbitrary strings of $X$'s and $P$'s. But that's a separate point.

Comment: They are both valid questions, and I'm not disagreeing that it would probably be hard to actually measure some arbitrary strings of $X$'s and $P$'s. My main point is that these are two separate questions. Quantum mechanics doesn't tell you what you *should* measure. Just, what you would get, *if* you measured something.

Comment: @Andrew I think that's a fair analysis. The heart of my question is whether we have any reason to suspect it's possible to do this construction though. I just don't see any evidence that it is. Where you say "annoying and hard", I think it might actually be "impossible". I'm looking for any information on whether it's just hard or perhaps impossible. I see that QM doesn't rule it out, but it doesn't guarantee the physical existence of the relevant Hamiltonians either. The latter point, I guess, is my concern.

Comment: It's not impossible mathematically, which makes me think it's not probably impossible *in principle*. But, it could well be that no one knows how to make this probe, or that it is wildly impractical with any conceivable technology. But, I don't know.

Comment: My one thought is that you can always use the commutation relations to put an arbitrary string of $X$'s and $P$'s into the form $X^n P^m + N i \hbar$, for some $n$, $m$, and $N$. So you "only" need to find a probe that couples to $X^n P^m$. Again, not sure if that's practically possible for arbitrary $n$ and $m$, but at least it reduces the space of possibilities a little bit.

Comment: If it were impossible to measure the expectation value of some hermitian operator for *fundamental* reasons, this would mean quantum theory as we understand it is incorrect.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch In some sense, that's the motivation for asking this question. Why is this not a major problem in the foundations of QM? If QM is good, then these quantities should be measurable. So how can we measure them?

Comment: I fear from your last comment that I didn't make the point clear. I don't want to go on and on, so I'll just comment one more time. The foundations of quantum mechanics do not care how you would build an experimental probe in a lab. It is only are concerned with statements like "**if** you measured operator $O$ in state $\Psi$, what would you see?" Since that question can be answered unambiguously, that's all that needs to be said at a foundational level. A classical analog of what you are asking would be: why isn't it a problem that we don't observe systems with a Hamiltonian $H=p^n q^n$?

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics I recommend reading a textbook on quantum information, in particular on generalized measurements, Naimark's theorem, and universal gate sets. What you are asking *is* understood.